# Why dependency is triggered even if an activity is made as an obsolete?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

In UCM project we are trying to deliver activity to default stream.

It is displaying that activity is having dependency with another activity.

As the dependent activity has no useful info we obsoleted it. But still it doesn't allow us to proceed and it force us to deliver that ?

Why dependency is being triggered even if the activity is obsolete?

Comment: Just added another option (not tested), in order to avoid seeing that obsolete activity in his/her deliver activity list.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu .. did this get resolved ?

Comment: @Pulak Agrawal : we removed the activity with admin's help. we were not able to solve by ourselves

Answer (score 2):

The activity will be associated with your deliver (without choice) if:

- there is a common file with other activities (file dependency)
- you previously did a deliver to *another* stream (in which case it automatically link all the remaining activities together)

If the activity is small enough, the best course of action remains to deliver everything, and to cancel what you don't need.

If there is *really* no common file, one option mentioned in this [old 2003 thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=46267#2930236) would be to try and **change the owner** (only by a ClearCase admin) of the activity.
See [cleartool project](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_protect.htm):

```
cleartool protect -chown aNewOwner activity:anActivity@\aPvob
```

(you might have to "`cleartool unlock activity:anActivity@\aPvob`" first if it was "`lock -obsolete`")

Comment: Can we delete the activity as it is not needed but some how dependency alone was created?

Comment: @Samselvaprabu not sure because I believe you can delete an activity only if it is empty. Which means you must first move the versions in *another* activity. And that only repeat the problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

@Samselvaprabu I have seen this happen before, this smells of hyperlinks. Can not be 100% sure if your problem is exactly same, but they have worked for me in the past:

1. - checkvob -ucm activity:@\PVOB
     which might point you to a bad hyperlink
   - checkvob -fix
2. Use ucmutil to do a similar job

Please be careful, there are always risks associated with messing with hyperlinks, so read the manuals and/or technotes before you actually run a checkvob -fix or something intrusive.